# Load balancing on oracle (12r2) 2 node RAC is not working

Tags: oracle-12c, rac, load-balancing

Any help/pointers would be greatly appreciated.

I have a 2 node RAC (Oracle 12r2) on linux,

- CRS and all its services are up.
- Both the RAC instances are up.
- scan listener resolves to 3 ip's.

But all the sessions from application go to only one node (RAC node 2).

and I see on my RAC node1 in the alert log file below error,

On WAS Console we have `jdbc:oracle:thin:@myscan.mydomain.com:1521/mypdbservicename.mydomain.com`

Not able connect to my pdb database using the service name via slqplus and via sql developer...

```
1)

Sqlplus schemaname/pwd@mypdb  --- fails

2)

sqlplus / as sysdba

alter session set container=mypdb;

Conn schemaname/pwd@mypdb failing --- fails
```

NOTE:   tnsping works

My Listener log consists the following:

```
<msg time='2019-08-23T07:09:36.992-04:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='RAC-01'
 host_addr='192.168.119.12' pid='17312'>
 <txt>23-AUG-2019 07:09:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=RAC-01)(USER=grid))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=LISTENER)(VERSION=203424000)) * status * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2019-08-23T07:09:37.994-04:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='RAC-01'
 host_addr='192.168.119.12' pid='17312'>
 <txt>23-AUG-2019 07:09:37 * service_update * +ASM1 * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2019-08-23T07:10:36.991-04:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='RAC-01'
 host_addr='192.168.119.12' pid='17312'>
 <txt>23-AUG-2019 07:10:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=RAC-01)(USER=grid))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=LISTENER)(VERSION=203424000)) * status * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2019-08-23T07:11:36.990-04:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='RAC-01'
 host_addr='192.168.119.12' pid='17312'>
 <txt>23-AUG-2019 07:11:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=RAC-01)(USER=grid))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=LISTENER)(VERSION=203424000)) * status * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2019-08-23T07:12:36.985-04:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='RAC-01'
 host_addr='192.168.119.12' pid='17312'>
 <txt>23-AUG-2019 07:12:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=RAC-01)(USER=grid))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=LISTENER)(VERSION=203424000)) * status * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2019-08-23T07:13:36.992-04:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='RAC-01'
 host_addr='192.168.119.12' pid='17312'>
 <txt>23-AUG-2019 07:13:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=RAC-01)(USER=grid))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=LISTENER)(VERSION=203424000)) * status * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2019-08-23T07:14:36.989-04:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='RAC-01'
 host_addr='192.168.119.12' pid='17312'>
 <txt>23-AUG-2019 07:14:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=RAC-01)(USER=grid))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=LISTENER)(VERSION=203424000)) * status * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2019-08-23T07:15:36.987-04:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='RAC-01'
 host_addr='192.168.119.12' pid='17312'>
 <txt>23-AUG-2019 07:15:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=RAC-01)(USER=grid))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=LISTENER)(VERSION=203424000)) * status * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2019-08-23T07:16:05.417-04:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='RAC-01'
 host_addr='192.168.119.12' pid='17312'>
 <txt>23-AUG-2019 07:16:05 * service_update * Rac1* 0
 </txt>
</msg>
<msg time='2019-08-23T07:16:36.991-04:00' org_id='oracle' comp_id='tnslsnr'
 type='UNKNOWN' level='16' host_id='RAC-01'
 host_addr='192.168.119.12' pid='17312'>
 <txt>23-AUG-2019 07:16:36 * (CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=)(HOST=RAC-01)(USER=grid))(COMMAND=status)(ARGUMENTS=64)(SERVICE=LISTENER)(VERSION=203424000)) * status * 0
 </txt>
</msg>
```

Comment: Hello, did you check your VIP resolution in the listener?  Also, what is in your listener.log?

Comment: updated my post with listener log file contents... sorry the formatting was not good... i cant even connect to my pdb database via slqplus or cant make connection using SQL Developer --- >  Sqlplus to pdb failing
Conn schemaname/pwd@pdb failing

Comment: Check your vip configuration in clusterware.  You have to use srvctl to add the vip addresses and associate the nodes to those vip address.  Check on how to configure node vips using srvctl commands.

Comment: - With Modified JDBC parameter Both WAS & Jetty are working as expected
o DB connection count are balanced

Answer (score 0):

- With Modified JDBC parameter Both WAS & Jetty are working as expected and DB connection count are balanced on the both nodes.

On RAC nodes, i have changed the tnsnames.ora -> to include the fully qualified global service name (including domain name) and it fixed sql connectivity issues.